# How to create a python script to ssh and run commands on multiple linux devices

Tags: python, linux

I've been scalping to find an explained python script to ssh to multiple Linux devices via ssh using paramiko. I found a few tweaked them and actually worked but i still cannot understand how it works.

Can someone please explain in the most appealing way how a python script to ssh to multiple Linux device and run commands works? Just as you would explain to a 6 year old. I mean I saw some scripts and they haver some complexity for no reason. I just wanted a Python script that imports a txt of hostnames and a another txt of commands and runs the same commands to all the Linux devices and returns the output. If someone could explain how such a script works I would be grateful.

```
ip = input("Please enter the hostname ")
user = ""
password = ""

print ("creating ssh")
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print("please wait")
ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip, username=user, password=password)

cmd= "uname -r;pwd"
print("please wait")
sdtin,stdout,stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
print("success")
stdout = stdout.readlines()
stdout = "".join(stdout)
print (stdout)
```

I want this but for multiple devices and getting the hostnames and commands from 2 separate files.

Comment: you've attached no code example to your question so it's quite impossible to explain how such a code would work or if you are correct that some complexity is there for no reason

Comment: i did now can you check ?

Comment: Hi Romario, Welcome to StackOverfow! What does your current code do? Does it create errors? 

Also if i may ask is python a hard requirement for this task or could it be a simple bash script?

Comment: Hi @marxmacher yes i would like to do it in python this script (no errors as it is ) logs in to a device that runs SSH and executes a command well i would like to do it on multiple devices with 1 script .

Comment: sequentialy or parallel?

Comment: sequentially is just fine

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community hello i just did i hope its good enough 
thanks :)

Comment: @romariostani instead of fighting yourself with python and paramiko you can use ansible to do that. ( it is based also on paramiko but it is easier to do stuff out of the box instead building each command in python ). I know that this is not an answer to your specific question but I hope that this is a better idea for your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I've found the answer (the perfect script for what I want).
Here it is:

```
import paramiko
import time
p = paramiko.SSHClient()
cred = open("hostnames.csv","r")
for i in cred.readlines():
        line=i.strip()
        ls =line.split(",")
        print(ls[0])
        p.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        p.connect("%s"%ls[0],port =22, username = "%s"%ls[1], password="%s"%ls[2])
        stdin, stdout, stderr = p.exec_command('sudo pwd' , get_pty=True)
        stdin.write("%s\n"%ls[2])
        stdin.flush()
        opt = stdout.readlines()
        opt ="".join(opt)
        print(opt)
cred.close()
```

So, it basically reads the csv file with is formatted as : hostname,username,password
and runs the script sequentially. Also, it can run `sudo` commands this way :)